# Connect to 2 Oracle Databases in Python

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to 2 Oracle databases in a single Python script and am having some trouble connecting to the second database. The error I am receiving is:

"DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

My login information is correct so I am confused on why it is not allowing me to access the second database. Any insight would be appreciated.

Sample code below:

```
dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("database1", "port_for_db1", "sid_for_db1") 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("myusername","password_db1",dsn=dsnStr)  

dsnStr2 = cx_Oracle.makedsn("database2", "port_for_db2", "sid_for_db2") 
conn2 = cx_Oracle.connect("myusername","password_db2",dsn=dsnStr)
```

Thank you!

Comment: try to connect it other database applications, like dbeaver or Navicat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake `dsn=dsnStr`

```
  dsnStr2 = cx_Oracle.makedsn("database2", "port_for_db2", "sid_for_db2") 
    conn2 = cx_Oracle.connect("myusername","password_db2",dsn=dsnStr2)
```